# NGINX, a lot of errors appear in the error_log even without logging in

Tags: nginx

I have a problem. Below I put the error_log:

```
2021/06/01 12:15:27 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/myadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /myadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:28 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/myadmin2/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /myadmin2/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:28 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /xampp/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:28 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyadmin_bak/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyadmin_bak/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:28 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/www/phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /www/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:29 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/tools/phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /tools/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:29 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin-old/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmyadmin-old/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:29 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdminold/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdminold/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:29 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin.old/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin.old/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:30 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pma-old/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /pma-old/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:30 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/claroline/phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /claroline/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:30 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /typo3/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:30 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpma/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpma/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:31 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:31 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:31 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAbmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAbmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:32 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin__/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin__/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:32 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin+++---/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin+++---/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:32 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/v/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /v/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:32 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadm1n/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmyadm1n/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:33 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdm1n/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdm1n/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:33 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/shaAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /shaAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:33 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyadmi/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyadmi/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:34 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmion/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmion/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:34 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/s/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /s/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:34 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/MyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /MyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:35 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin1/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin1/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:35 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin123/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin123/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:35 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/pwd/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /pwd/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:35 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmina/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmina/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:36 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMydmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMydmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:36 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmins/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmins/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:36 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin._/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin._/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:36 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin._2/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin._2/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:37 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin2222/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmyadmin2222/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:37 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin333/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin333/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:37 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin3333/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmyadmin3333/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:37 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/php2MyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /php2MyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:38 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpiMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpiMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:38 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpNyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpNyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:38 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/1/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /1/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:39 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/download/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /download/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:39 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin_111/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin_111/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:39 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:39 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/321/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /321/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:40 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/123131/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /123131/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:40 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdminn/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdminn/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:41 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdminhf/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdminhf/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:41 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sbb/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /sbb/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:41 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/WWW/phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /WWW/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:42 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmln/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmln/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:42 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMyAdmin_ai/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpMyAdmin_ai/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:42 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/__phpMyAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /__phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:42 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/program/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /program/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:43 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/shopdb/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /shopdb/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:43 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phppma/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phppma/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:43 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpmy/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /phpmy/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:44 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysql/admin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /mysql/admin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:46 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysql/dbadmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /mysql/dbadmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:46 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysql/sqlmanager/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /mysql/sqlmanager/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:47 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysql/mysqlmanager/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /mysql/mysqlmanager/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:47 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /wp-content/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/wp-pma-mod/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:47 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sqladmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /sqladmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:48 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sql/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /sql/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:49 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/SQL/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /SQL/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:49 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/websql/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /websql/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:50 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/MySQLAdmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /MySQLAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:53 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/manager/html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:54 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/axis2/axis2-admin/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "POST /axis2/axis2-admin/login HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:54 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /login HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
2021/06/01 12:15:55 [error] 208524#0: *17 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/jenkins/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.18.206.22, server: 95.141.35.62, request: "GET /jenkins/login HTTP/1.1", host: "95.141.35.62"
```

Can anyone help me understand how to prevent these errors? I want to clarify that they appeared when I didn't even log into the server. In the nginx.conf file I have set all the locations and files well. On the server I only installed nginx and nothing else. But it seems that the server can't find something important ... can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You can't prevent this and shouldn't worry either

These "errors" will happen whenever somebody (or more likely *something*) requests a file from your webserver that doesn't exist.

Such an error message might be an error in your site and indicate a dead link, but that is not the case here.

---

Whenever a system is accessible to the internet at large and responding to connection requests you will almost immediately and continuously see (mostly automated) probes making such connections.

Once connected to a webserver such probes will try to either crawl your website (for example to index your site for a search engine), or more commonly, they try to determine what software and which versions you are running.

Once a specific software package(s) has been found you will usually see subsequent attempts to abuse known vulnerabilities in that package.

> ```
> "/usr/share/nginx/html/phpMydmin/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)
> ```

This for example looks for a phpMyAdmin, which is commonly installed in a default directory `phpMyAdmin`  (and too often both publicly accessible not regularly updated, leaving it vulnerable to one of the many new vulnerabilities that regularly get found, disclosed and fixed in a new release).

You don't have phpMyAdmin installed (there), hence the "file not found" error.  Then the probe continues to attempt locate it in other common locations, `/xampp/phpmyadmin/` , `/tools/phpMyAdmin/` etc. Failing that the probe may scan for other commonly installed tools, or move on to the next IP-address.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So what can I do to avoid these errors in the error_log or prevent anyone from accessing those non-existent files?

Comment: You could try to prevent random clients from accessing your webserver (with for example a firewall), but that generally defats the purpose of having a webserver and a (public) website...

Answer (score 1):

Most requests are targeted to an IP address, not a specific domain. If the virtual host is the `default` virtual host, it means all requests are processed by that block.

You should create a virtual host for your own domain, and disable logging for your default virtual host.

The configuration looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server; # Make default virtual host

    server_name _; # Dummy host name

    access_log off; # Disable access.log

    return 404; # Return 404 error to all requests
}

server {
    listen 80; # Listen to HTTP port

    server_name example.com; # Domain name for the virtual host

    ... # Rest of the configuration
}
```

However, once bots learn about your domain name, you will get your share of these requests. Then you can further filter requests by matching user-agents that definitely aren't used by your visitors.

Another alternative is to use a provider like Cloudflare that filters most of this traffic so that it doesn't reach your server.